# Can't save notebook: first argument must String or instance of Buffer

Tags: azure-data-studio

I don't really have any troubleshooting steps because I have no idea what to try. Googling resulted in people getting that error when there are issues in the code they wrote, but I'm just trying to save a SQL notebook in Azure Data Studio.
[Image of Azure Data Studio error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZFt.png)

> Error: Failed to save filename. The first argument must be of type String or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of object.

It seems to happen randomly. I'll open a notebook and for 20 minutes or so I can save no problem, then this issue starts popping up. All of the code cells run as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an answer to the question, however using the Azure Data Studio Insiders edition seems to have fixed the issue.